# how to check if values are null before entering into database?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a php function

```
function insertIntoDb($db, $table) {
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table);
    $fieldnames=array();
      if (mysql_num_rows($resultInsert) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
            $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
            $values = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) ); #check if value is null otherwise do not INSERT
        }
      }
      $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ("%s")', $table, 
      implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values))); 
      mysql_query($sql); 
      echo '<div class="success">Data was entered into the database successfully!<br><a href="view.php?type=recent">View listing?</a></div>';
}
```

Basically I am using the table columns to generate fields for a user form, then using that same method to insert into the table. Currently it is working, however how do I check if the values being entered are empty (for example user hasnt filled out a field) before inserting it into the table?

Comment: `if(empty($userInput)){ echo "empty input";}` ?

Comment: My brain is a little fried at the moment due to sleep deprivation, but I'm just not wrapping it around your code.  Why do you need to check for nulls?  To avoid throwing MySQL errors?  Empty HTML form fields show up in PHP as empty strings rather than null values, so would you really have nulls in the first place?  Unless you're talking about checkboxes that aren't checked.  In that case just check for their presence using `isset($values['checkboxName'])`.

Comment: i clarified the quesiton. isset and empty w the actual field name is an interesting notion, but since all the fields are dynamically added in you could not specify the field name

Comment: You need Javascript/jQuery validation before submit so you don't need to check for empty values before inserting.

Comment: you need to explain the problem better to yourself to get an answer I think. Do you need to prevent null user-entry (forgetting fields) or to prevent null insertion? This is different.

Comment: @AnriëtteCombrink client side validation should never exclude server-side validation.

Comment: prevent null insertion... the validation on the client side is kindof a moot point right now

Answer (score 3):

Some good thing to know about checking for null/not-set/empty values:

### Null congruence (`===`):

```
$result = $x === NULL
```

or

```
$result = is_null($x)
// $result === TRUE if:
// $x was never set
// was set to NULL
```

### `isset`

```
$result = isset($x['some_key'])
// $result === TRUE if $x['some_key'] is either:
// NULL
// does not exist in $x (was never set)
```

### Is `empty`:

```
if(empty($x))
// $result === TRUE if $x is either:
// NULL
// FALSE
// (int) 0
// (float) 0.0
// (string) ''
// (string) '0'
```

The speed of the above operations is listed in order:

- `===` / `!==` because they are operators
- `isset` / `empty` because they are language constructs (not functions)
- `is_null` because it is a function

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
    $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
    $values = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) );
}
```

With this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
$values = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) );
$values = array_filter($values, function($x) { return $x !== ''; });
```

If you are using PHP < 5.3, you need to replace that last line with this:

```
$values = array_filter($values, create_function('$x', 'return $x !== "";'));
```

Comment: It does two things: (1) fixes a bug in your code which (I believe) causes only the data for the last DB column to be inserted, (2) removes all empty strings from the `$values` array.

Comment: A much better way to remove all emptystrings/nulls from an array is array_filter($values)

Comment: @MihaiStancu The one problem with array_filter() is that it will also remove the string "0", which may be a desired form field value.

Comment: That's a problem when you use the default callback but you can specify the callback.

Comment: I'm betting that if you specify the callback it performs more poorly than array_diff() since it requires a function call for every element of the array. However, I have not tested this.

Comment: Just tested; you are right, array_filter() is faster by 20x. I'll edit my answer momentarily.

Comment: Careful, your anonymous function callback only works in `PHP > 5.3` before that you need to define the filtering function separately.